# create a wizard/plugin which generates a new project in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I want to create a wizard/plugin which generates a new project. The generated 
project is similar with the Web Dynamic project  but with some specific 
configuration and some folder. The end result I wish to achieve in terms of 
structure of dynamic web project with my configuration and my given folder.

> [plugin to create new project]={Web Dynamic project}+{my given folder
>   and some configuration}

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a new project nature.

You can find an example in eclipse, if you create a new RCP plugin project , then at the end of the wizard, it allows you to select a template (with code). Select `Plugin with an incremental project builder`. This will give you an example

Other [tutorial](https://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-4-create-a-custom-project-in-eclipse-new-project-wizard-the-behavior/)

Comment: I want to create my own web dynamic project which have as the structure of web dynamic project with my given folder

Comment: I think my solution are  not in RCP.